# Finding the index of the first element (e.g "True") from a series/column

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

How do I find the index of an element (e.g "True") in a series or a column?

For example I have a column, where I want to identify the first instance where an event occur. So I write it as

```
Variable = df["Force"] < event
```

This then creates a boolen series of Data where it is False, until the first instance it becomes True. How then do I find the index of data point?

Is there are better way?

Answer (score 33):

Use `idxmax` to find the first instance of the maximum value.  In this case, `True` is the maximum value.

```
df['Force'].lt(event).idxmax()
```

Consider the sample `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Force=[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]), list('abcde'))
df

   Force
a      5
b      4
c      3
d      2
e      1
```

The first instance of `Force` being less than `3` is at index `'d'`.

```
df['Force'].lt(3).idxmax()
'd'
```

Be aware that if no value for `Force` is less than 3, then the maximum will be `False` and the first instance will be the first one.

Also consider the alternative `argmax`

```
df.Force.lt(3).values.argmax()
3
```

It returns the position of the first instance of maximal value.  You can then use this to find the corresponding `index` value:

```
df.index[df.Force.lt(3).values.argmax()]
'd'
```

Also, in the future, `argmax` will be a Series method.

Comment: Greetings, Thanks for this. It is a much easier way than writing a loop. It works great.

Answer (score 7):

You can also try [`first_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index.html) with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html).

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[5], [4], [3], [2], [1]], columns=["Force"])
df.Force.where(df.Force < 3).first_valid_index()
3
```

`where` will replace the part that does not meet the condition with `np.nan` *by default*. Then, we find the first valid index out of the series.

---

Or this: select a subset of the item that you are interested in, here `Variable == 1`. Then find the first item in its index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[5], [4], [3], [2], [1]], columns=["Force"])
v = (df["Force"] < 3)
v[v == 1].index[0]
```

---

Bonus: if you need the index of first appearance of many kinds of items, you can use `drop_duplicates`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["yello"], ["yello"], ["blue"], ["red"],  ["blue"], ["red"]], columns=["Force"])  
df.Force.drop_duplicates().reset_index()
    index   Force
0   0       yello
1   2       blue
2   3       red
```

Some more work...

```
df.Force.drop_duplicates().reset_index().set_index("Force").to_dict()["index"]
{'blue': 2, 'red': 3, 'yello': 0}
```

Answer (score 5):

Below is a non-pandas solution which I find easy to adapt:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Force=[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]), list('abcde'))

next(idx for idx, x in zip(df.index, df.Force) if x < 3)  # d
```

It works by iterating to the first result of a generator expression.

Pandas appears to perform poorly in comparison:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Force=np.random.randint(0, 100000, 100000)))

n = 99900

%timeit df['Force'].lt(n).idxmin()
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.57 ms per loop

%timeit df.Force.where(df.Force > n).first_valid_index()
# 100 loops, best of 3: 1.61 ms per loop

%timeit next(idx for idx, x in zip(df.index, df.Force) if x > n)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 100 µs per loop
```

Comment: Nice approach, with a fair performance evaluation. If one wants to avoid the `StopIteration` exception in case no element meets the condition, just use `next` with a default value, for example: `next(gen, None)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an all-pandas solution that I consider a little neater than some of the other answers. It is also able to handle the corner case where no value of the input series satisfies the condition.

```py
def first_index_ordered(mask):
    assert mask.index.is_monotonic_increasing
    assert mask.dtype == bool
    idx_min = mask[mask].index.min()
    return None if pd.isna(idx_min) else idx_min

col = "foo"
thr = 42
mask = df[col] < thr
idx_first = first_index_ordered(mask)
```

The above assumed that `mask` has a value-ordered, monotonically increasing index. If this is not the case, we have to do a bit more:

```py
def first_index_unordered(mask):
    assert mask.dtype == bool
    index = mask.index
    # This creates a RangeIndex, which is monotonic
    mask = mask.reset_index(drop=True)
    idx_min = mask[mask].index.min()
    return None if pd.isna(idx_min) else index[idx_min]
```

Of course, we can combine both cases in one function:

```py
def first_index_where(mask):
    if mask.index.is_monotonic_increasing:
        return first_index_ordered(mask)
    else:
        return first_index_unordered(mask)
```