# How to select the next date in a Pandas dataframe with date index and missing dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe indexed on date with some dates missing (that's ok, they are non-trading data and this is stock data).

How do I access the next row, when I know the previous date, e.g.

```
date  Open
01-01-2021  501
02-01-2021  508
04-01-2021  511
05-01-2021  518
```

I would like a function that, when I input '02-01-2021', it outputs the values for 04-01-2021 (without knowing how many days in between might be missing. I am assuming there may be some iterator, or index number I can access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a compare  with the `date` column and return `head(1)` for the immediate next row:

```
inp = '02-01-2021'
df[df['date']>'02-01-2021'].head(1)
```

---

```
        date  Open
2 2021-04-01   511
```

Note: this is assuming `date` is a column and the dtype is a `datetime` and the date column is sorted by date.

Comment: Had to change it a bit, but the following worked: next = df[df.index > day].head(1)['Open']

Comment: @dorien I see, `date` is an index then, you can also use loc : `df.loc[df.index > day,'Open'].head(1)`, Glad you figured..!!

Answer (score 3):

If the rows are sorted by *date*, use [searchsorted](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html):

```
idx = df['date'].searchsorted(pd.to_datetime('02-01-2021'), side='right')
print(df.loc[idx, 'date'])
```

**Output**

```
2021-04-01 00:00:00
```

The time complexity of searchsorted is *O(logN)*. Otherwise, use:

```
idx = df['date'].gt(pd.to_datetime('02-01-2021')).idxmax()
print(df.loc[idx, 'date'])
```

**Output**

```
2021-04-01 00:00:00
```

A third alternative is to use [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
date = pd.to_datetime('02-01-2021')
idx = next(i for i, x in zip(df.index, df['date']) if x > date)
print(df.loc[idx, 'date'])
```

Although it needs benchmarking, the last alternative could be faster for unordered data according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48649272/4001592).